# Including OpenCV in C++ project on Eclipse does not work

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, include

[image]

Hello everyone,
In the image above I've screencaptured my screen, where we can see OpenCV is well included and everything is at its place, but the compiler seems to not find the header file.

I've included it in the properties of the project, under GCC C++ Compiler include paths.
I do not know what to do now...

If you have a clue, it'll be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Bye!

Comment: Please show that path you have added to the project, and the `#include` statement you have used. Usually in this situation one of these is wrong, but unless you show what you actually used no-one can do more than guess what the problem is. Also please include these two items as **text** in the question, not as a link to an image.

Comment: Looks like you used the wrong path to the opencv header. Shouldn't it be `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` with that said you did not show the setting you added to the include directories.